# How to get data using nested maps in single render?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to print the data as given below.[image] .I have used the nested map in the render wherein the first map is to print the Category name and the link view all.And in the second/nested map i'm trying to loop over the data belonging to the category as listed in the parent map.
But i'm getting an error as [unexpected token at nested return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVrxM.jpg) .
 [image]

render function in FeaturedSection.js

```
  <div className="data-container">
    <div  className="row mx-0">
      {this.state.newData && Object.keys(groupedByCategory).map(function(categoryName,i)
        {return(
          <div key={i}  className="row mx-0">
              <div className="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 lrPadding">
                <h3 className="featureTitle">Featured {`${categoryName}`}</h3>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 lrPadding">
                <Link to="#" className="routeDecorator ">
                <h5 className="featureTitle float-right mt-3">View All
                 <i className="fa fa-angle-right font-weight-bold px-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </h5>
                </Link>
              </div>
              groupedByCategory[categoryName].map(function(data,i)
                {
                  return (

                        <FeaturedOffer
                          title={data.name}
                          offerDescription={data.offerdescription}
                          rewardImage={data.reward_image}
                          productName={data.modelname}
                          thumbnailImage={data.thumbnailimage}
                        />
                );
              })
          </div>
        );})}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks @Striped but that wasn't the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to wrap your map within `{}`.

```
{ 
  groupedByCategory[categoryName].map((data,i) => {(
    <FeaturedOffer
      key={i}
      title={data.name}
      offerDescription={data.offerdescription}
      rewardImage={data.reward_image}
      productName={data.modelname}
      thumbnailImage={data.thumbnailimage}
    />
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Striped.I had forgotten to wrap it within `{ }`.But i shouldn't include `{( <FeatureOffer /> )}`

Comment: It just a shorthand to omit the return statement.